# Android Pointer Indicies vs Identifiers

Tags: android

I'm reading through Beginning Android Games(for Beginners), which I must say has been very helpful.

I'm on the topic of handling Multi-touch events, and by far the part that is **most confusing** is the difference between *pointer indexes* and *identifiers(ID's)*. I understand that the indexes aren't always corresponding to the number of fingers, but what about the ID's?

Say I put 3 fingers down on the screen; could I assume that the first finger would have `Index var`, and for the `ID 0`. Second finger `Index var` and `ID 1`, and so on? Do the ID's always correspond in that manner and if they don't, what is the `Identifier` of the finger?